# save in excel file different column

Tags: r

I am looking for a code I can export results in each iteration in each specific cell in excel

```
for(i in data_length)
{
    D <- d[[i]] * 100
    write.csv(D, file = "path directory")
}
```

I need a code to save in same excel file but in different row and column

Comment: Your code so far uses `write.csv` which is appropriate for a *comma-separated value* (`.csv`) file, not an Excel (`.xls` or `.xlsx`) file. Do you need to save results in an actual Excel file, or is CSV okay?

Comment: Hello Fatima. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post. As currently stated, your question is too ambiguous to answer. For example, the contents of `d[[i]]` are unclear.

Comment: you surely want to set the `append` param of `write.csv()` to `TRUE`.
`write.csv(D, file="file", append=T)` might work if your data (which you unfortunately did not supply) allows for it

Comment: I am not sure about the line which save result into excel but the things I have in mind is to save result one by one into 1 excel file in different column and row..Could you suggest me the command line for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example based on the RDCOMClient package to export data to specific Excel cells :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE

path_To_Excel_File <- "D:/Excel_File.xlsx"
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_To_Excel_File, ReadOnly = TRUE)
sheet <- xlWbk$sheets(1)

for(i in 1 : 4)
{
  for(j in 1 : 4)
  {
    cell <- sheet$cells(i, j)
    cell[["Value"]] <- i + j
  }
}
```